# How do I stop this hover popup in Phpstorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When hovering over code in Phpstorm, I get a popup like below.  Every hover produces a similar popup like these below:

[image]

[image]

Edit:  I've realized the popups only occur during live edit.

But I still cant find a setting to turn them off.

Comment: Post some code instread of pictures.

Comment: Its not a programming issue. Please post  questions in proper forms.

Comment: It's any and all code in the editor which causes the popups.  So I'm not sure adding code will clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't be turned off.

This is part of "inspections" (validations) which I think is necessary in any editor to prevent syntax and run-time errors. PHPStorm goes a step further than something like Eclipse (which has validations but lets you disable the pop-ups), and as far as I can tell, the PHPStorm developers are not interested in an option to disable the pop-ups. I have no clue why as they constantly get in the way of me clicking or typing.